# Download property in HTML tag not working with BLOB file

Tags: javascript, html, file, download, blob

I am working on a project on my website [Click here to go to project site](http://veryblankwhitepaper.weebly.com/text-file-generator.html),
but after inputting all the needed information, the download  element does not work. Here is the code for the download link: The download may work on this website, but it doesn't work on my website, which is strange.

```html
<a id="down" href="blob:http://veryblankwhitepaper.weebly.com/8d869eaa-5bce-4326-9dff-dd0b50286a84" download="filename.txt">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

For some reason, when I click this, nothing happens.
If you want, you can see the javascript [here](https://veryblankwhitepaper.weebly.com/files/theme/canvas.js).
Scroll down to the scripts within the "/text-file-generator.html"
(I put all the scripts for my pages in one file)

Edit1: If I take the element out of the div that it is in, it seems to work, but I want it to still be in the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scripts change the link too quickly. Try adding a setTimeout function for half a second when you click the link. This should allow it to download.